# how to get content with parsing multiple htmls files

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I have stored some html files and I want to get  title, meta tags and content , problem is when I echo this without loop and csv its printing all the data , but when I am trying to put that data in csv file only first two columns are being saved in csv file.

It work good if I parse single html file without csv generation.

Here is the code

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$myfiles = scandir("bella");
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=acts_scarlet.csv');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$fieldArr['field_name']['title']       = 'Title';
$fieldArr['field_name']['description'] = 'Meta Description';
$fieldArr['field_name']['keywords']    = 'Meta keywords';
$fieldArr['field_name']['heading']     = 'Heading points';
$fieldArr['field_name']['content']     = 'Description';

fputcsv($file, $fieldArr['field_name']);

foreach ($myfiles as $value) {

    $fieldArr=array();
    $content='';
    $heading='';
    $title='';
    $description='';
    $keywords='';

    $exp=explode('.', $value);
 
    if($exp[1]=='html')
    {
        $html = file_get_contents("bella/".$value);
        $dom = new DomDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($html);       
        $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
        //get and display what you need:
        $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $metas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');


        for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
        {
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description'){
               $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
            }
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords'){
                $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
            }

        }
         $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

        // get highlighted texts
        foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class, "reason")]/node()') as $childNode) {
          $heading .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
        }

        // get description 
        foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@id, "act-bio")]/node()') as $childNode) {
          $content .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
        }

        $fieldArr['field_value']['title']       = $title;
        $fieldArr['field_value']['description'] = $description;
        $fieldArr['field_value']['keywords']    = strip_tags($keywords);
        $fieldArr['field_value']['heading']     = strip_tags($heading);
        $fieldArr['field_value']['content']     = strip_tags($content);

        fputcsv($file, $fieldArr['field_value']);
    }
}


fclose($file);
die();
?>
```

[output in csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcErM.png)

This is the working code with single script

```
$result='';
$result2='';

$html = file_get_contents("bella/tour.html");
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description'){
       echo $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords'){
        $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        echo "<br>";
    }

}

// get highlighted texts
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class, "reason")]/node()') as $childNode) {
  $result .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
}

echo $result;

// get description 
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@id, "act-bio")]/node()') as $childNode) {
   $result2 .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
}

echo $result2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$myfiles = scandir("bella");
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=acts_scarlet.csv');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$fieldArr['field_name']['title']       = 'Title';
$fieldArr['field_name']['description'] = 'Meta Description';
$fieldArr['field_name']['keywords']    = 'Meta keywords';
$fieldArr['field_name']['heading']     = 'Heading points';
$fieldArr['field_name']['content']     = 'Description';

fputcsv($file, $fieldArr['field_name']);
$data = []; // +
foreach ($myfiles as $value) {

    $fieldArr=array();
    $content='';
    $heading='';
    $title='';
    $description='';
    $keywords='';

    $exp=explode('.', $value);
 
    if($exp[1]=='html')
    {
        $html = file_get_contents("bella/".$value);
        $dom = new DomDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($html);       
        $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
        //get and display what you need:
        $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $metas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');


        for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
        {
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description'){
               $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
            }
            if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords'){
                $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
            }

        }
         $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

        // get highlighted texts
        foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class, "reason")]/node()') as $childNode) {
          $heading .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
        }

        // get description 
        foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@id, "act-bio")]/node()') as $childNode) {
          $content .= $dom->saveHtml($childNode);
        }

        $fieldArr['field_value']['title']       = $title;
        $fieldArr['field_value']['description'] = $description;
        $fieldArr['field_value']['keywords']    = strip_tags($keywords);
        $fieldArr['field_value']['heading']     = strip_tags($heading);
        $fieldArr['field_value']['content']     = strip_tags($content);

        //fputcsv($file, $fieldArr['field_value']); // -
        $data[] = $fieldArr['field_value']; // +
    }
}

fputcsv($file, $data); // +
fclose($file);
die();
?>
```

Comment: not working , its putting all the array in one rows https://prnt.sc/BbKEv66kZ9wr

Comment: Can you show screenshot how it was before

Comment: Why should OP "try this"? What have you changed, what was the problem? Please always add some explanation so users can learn

Comment: @YaMus https://prnt.sc/W56eY3inRD7c, it was working like this , one row for each file

Comment: @brombeer, sure added the working code with single script